# Extracting values from a database to populate a dropdown

Tags: php, mysqli, html-select

I have a db, am trying to extract values into a list

Here is the code I am trying to run (I had to adapt it from elsewhere), which should return an array, from which I want to select the AllianceName attribute

```
<?php
//database connection file setting.inc will need to be modified for production
include ("settings.inc");

$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
if (!$con) {
  exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
           . mysqli_connect_error());
} 
//set the default client character set 
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf-8');
mysqli_select_db($dbname, $con);

$options = array();
$options[] = "<option value=''>--?--</option>";
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM `City`
GROUP BY `AllianceName`
";

$db = mysqli_query($query);
foreach ( $db as $d ) {
  $options[] = "<option value='{".$d['AllianceName']."}'></option>";
}
?>
<select class="" id="articles" size="1" name="articles">
<?php echo implode("\n", $options); ?>
</select>*/
```

Right now this only returns the --?-- that I have defined in the options array. It does not parse any of the values from the query. I know the query by itself is correct since I have run it exactly in this syntax in the SQL server and it works.

I am pretty sure that this is a syntax error ... var_dump($db) gives me a bool(false) output.

Here's the latest code I am using:

```
<?php
//database connection file setting.inc will need to be modified for production
include ("settings.inc");  

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
} 
?>
<select class="Select" id="articles" size="1" name="articles">
<?php
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT DISTINCT `AllianceName`
    FROM `City`
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo "<option value="'.{$row['AllianceName']}.'"></option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

The query by itself runs fine when I just echo the results. Trying to put it into a dropdown fails every time. No values get populated.

Comment: thanks, but you assume I didn't read up on the subject. I did, but much of the literature that I have come across is subject/case specific so what I have done is try to use the concepts in my own code example. Also, absolutely new coding language for me.

Comment: The point is not in *reading.* But in *running example codes*. And getting yourself familiar with basic actions. The very $result->fetch_assoc thing have to be gotten by means of tutorial, not by means of asking a question on Stack Overflow. This is not a tutorial site. It's just Q&A site. Means you have to be done with basic tutorial example before ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code that finally worked. Both @Syndrose and @Zombiehunter provided clues to this.

@Syndrose - you might want to take into account the syntax used here as this is what was failing from your codebase...especially the syntax for the echo  tag line.

```
<?php
//database connection file setting.inc will need to be modified for production
include ("settings.inc");  

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
} 
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT DISTINCT `AllianceName`
    FROM `City`
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
?>
<select  style="width:300px" class="" id="AllianceName" size="1" name="Alliance Name">
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo '<option value='.$row['AllianceName'].'>'.$row['AllianceName'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here.
First you don't need the `GROUP BY 'AllianceName'` in your query, you are not performing any functions on your data, that might have been causing you to not return any results.

Secondly, normally you loop through query results with a while loop. You don't have to, but its common practice, so your code should look like this..

```
<?php
//database connection file setting.inc will need to be modified for production
include ("settings.inc");  

$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");
if (!$con) {
  exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
       . mysqli_connect_error());
} 
//there is no need to make an array first, just have it spit out the options if you aren't making a class or function
?>
<select class="" id="articles" size="1" name="articles">
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `City` ";
$db = mysqli_query($query);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
  echo "<option value='{".$d['AllianceName']."}'></option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Try that out and see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried the exact code you provided me, and it didn't work.  The response I get in console is `<select class="" id="articles" size="1" name="articles">
</select>.`  I am trying to select distinct values, therefore the group by query, I changed that to "SELECT DISTINCT `AllianceName` from `City`" ... i know this query works in SQL just fine.  The output I get is just a blank dropdown box.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) docs:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So what you have after the query succeeded is a mysqli_result object. Now you have to fetch the result into an (associative) array or object, row by row.

```
if($query === false) die('Query failed to execute');

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['AllianceName'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

All this is described in hundreds of tutorials in the web, so please read one of these. I recommend these written in the current decade, e.g. http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: Thanks. Working through with the tutorial you pointed me at allowed me to echo back a successful query. Now I shall try to encapsulate that in a form/dropdown list.

Comment: so I got a result, but my real need is to encapsulate that result in a dropdown list, take a selected value as input from the user and trigger a second query. Right now, I can echo the output basis the tutorial, thanks...but can't get the same output parsed into a dropdown list. Posted the new code lower in my question.

Comment: ah nm. I got a result and thanks to both you and @Syndrose for elements of the answer. I will post what I finally did to a separate answer, and now I am beginning to understand the semantics of this coding method.